# How to access request Header, or HTTPServletRequest on Apache ISIS DomainService?

Tags: java, apache, servlets, jakarta-ee, isis

I have an apache ISIS webapplication with several Objects and RestfulServices.
For logging-purposes i need some information of the request itself, not only the parameters which should be send.
How can I access these Request-Header information?

I tried to get the `HttpServletRequest` via the `RequestCycle` object. Here is the code-line:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getContainerRequest();
```

When I create the objects via **apache wicket viewer** I get access to the `HttpServlerRequest` object and all the information of the request. But when I send the a request via the restful services I get a `NullpointerException` when I try to access the `RequestCycle`.

Do you have any idea how to access the request header in this domainservice?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

When you request with Restful services there is no Wicket RequestCycle at all because WicketFilter is not used for Restful requests.

I cannot help with the rest of the question. I have no experience with this.

Answer (score 2):

If all you require is the Accept headers, then you can use the [AcceptHeaderService](http://isis.apache.org/guides/rgsvc.html#_rgsvc_api_AcceptHeaderService).

If you need access to anything else then you'll have to roll-your-own.  But doing so should be quite easy; take a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/apache/isis/blob/rel/isis-1.12.1/core/viewer-restfulobjects-rendering/src/main/java/org/apache/isis/viewer/restfulobjects/rendering/service/acceptheader/AcceptHeaderServiceForRest.java) of aforementioned `AcceptHeaderService` along with where it is [registered](https://github.com/apache/isis/blob/rel/isis-1.12.1/core/viewer-restfulobjects-server/src/main/java/org/apache/isis/viewer/restfulobjects/server/RestfulObjectsApplication.java#L50) in `RestfulObjectsApplication`; you could provide a custom subclass of `RestfulObjectsApplication` in the [web.xml](https://github.com/apache/isis/blob/rel/isis-1.12.1/example/application/simpleapp/webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L247).